# Drag and drop sorting of table columns with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sorting, drag-and-drop

I'm using jQuery to drive my AJAX UI. I have a table of data, and I want to allow the user to reorder the columns in the table by dragging and dropping them. I'd like the user to be able to grab the header for a column and move it. The row of data underneath should follow. Note that I'm *not* interested in sorting the data or in reordering rows, but in allowing the user to change the order of the columns.

Is there an existing solution? I tried using the standard jQuery sortable call on the `<th>` elements, but of course that doesn't work. I browsed through the jQuery plugins site and didn't find anything. Will I need to write a jQuery plugin?

Edit: Note that jQuery, Dojo, etc. (the free ones) are really the only option for a JS framework. I can't get a license for anything commercial like ExtJS.

Comment: Do any of your rows span more than one column?

Comment: No. It's very straight-forward markup. I can post it, but I don't think it'll be too surprising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to pay for a license you might try Ext JS instead of just jQuery. There are some pretty powerful grid features that include what you are trying to do.

http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/array-grid.html

Comment: Sadly, there is no way I can talk the committee I work under into it. They are a bit tight-fisted. Thanks, though - it is just what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 16):

There's a JQuery UI Widget called [Dragtable](http://jebaird.com/blog/dragtable-jquery-ui-widget-re-arrange-table-columns-drag-drop).

[Live demo](http://jebaird.com/demos/dragtable/)

Answer (score 5):

Try this instead:

```js
$('.sort').sortable({
  cursor: 'move',
  axis: 'y',
  update: function(e, ui) {
    $(this).sortable('refresh');
    var params = {};
    params = $('.id').serializeArray(),
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          id : params
        },
        url: 'Your url',
        success: function(msg) {
          // Your sorted data.
        }
      });
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>abc</th>
      <th>xyz</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="sort">
    <tr>
      <input class="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="Your Value" />
      <td class="center"><span>Text Here</span></td>
      <td>Yes, you are done</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

Sorttable jquery UI library appears to do exactly what you want here.

https://github.com/dbrink/sorttable/wiki
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/sorttable

Comment: Note that this is not the same as Jquery UI Sortable (note the extra T in sorttable).

Comment: Good point. It is *a* sortable table that supports the functionality described that happens to use jQuery. As to quality, YMMV as I haven't used it, I just happened to notice it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another one that builds on top of the jquery-ui library http://akottr.github.io/dragtable/

Answer (score 2):

You should try [Dragtable by Danvk](http://www.danvk.org/wp/dragtable/)

I found this question while searching for a fix to a bug in it though. It doesn't like tables positioned in horizontally scrolling panels.

Aside from this it's fantastic.

Answer (score -1):

you mean something like this? [Table Drag and Drop JQuery plugin](http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/)

Comment: That handles rearrangement of _rows_ and OP specifically state that as not what he's looking for.