# Relocating a column and its Contents in HTML table layout

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm using a table for the report UI,

it will be like this

[image]

Now, I'm changing it like, I can rearrange the columns of the table so that I can easily make new rearranged reports.

Like:

[image]

I have done the table header with Jquery draggable and sortable. But have no idea , how to relocate the corresponding column with the header.

Please Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to get the index for that column from the `<thead>` and apply the move to all columns in the `tbody`.

There are a number of plugins available - see google https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery+ui+draggable+column to get results like

- http://akottr.github.io/dragtable/ (IE7+) see also http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-For-Draggable-Table-Columns-Dragtable/
- older SO question [Drag and drop sorting of table columns with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705525/drag-and-drop-sorting-of-table-columns-with-jquery)
- answer to SO question above lists both akkotr's dragtable.js and http://jebaird.com/demos/dragtable/ as example (forked from [akottr's dragtable](https://github.com/akottr/dragtable)).

akottr uses an approach that attaches a css class to the column you're trying to drag, gets the index for that column, finds the element for this index (with `thtb.find('> tr > td:nth-child(' + i + ')')`, then compares the original index with where you want to move the column to (see the function `_bubbleCols`)
this then uses a function called `swapNodes` that swaps the column chosen with the column at the new position.

there's some clever things like asynchronously re-arranging the table, dealing with inner tables, firefox fixes, comments on (un)supported msie behaviour etc