# HTML Table change positions of columns

Tags: javascript, html, css

Someone know how can I make a table html and when I click on one column i can drag column and put in other place in table html.

Example:

```
--------------------
|    Name    | Age |
--------------------
   David       11
   August      14
```

When I click on the `Age` column and drag to other position. This must be:

```
--------------------
| Age |    Name    |
--------------------
   11     David       
   14     August
```

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705525/drag-and-drop-sorting-of-table-columns-with-jquery helps you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty awesome UI Widget called "Dragtable" that handles this pretty well. There is an example on their site. [Check it out.](http://jebaird.com/2010/12/29/dragtable-a-jquery-ui-widget-to-re-arrange-table-columns-via-drag-and-drop.html)

This requires the use of jQuery - which you may be against. If you were to just use Javascript there are other methods. But they may not be as smooth (with drag-drop animations etc).

Happy coding!